# LR Analysis - Graph Data

Tags: loadrunner, raw-data

In the image, the vuser has ramped up at ***00:04:52***, but in graph data its showing ***00:04***. Is there a way to get accurate time in graph data. I know in raw data we will be able to fetch the details in form of scenario elapsed time [secs] but in this we wont get ***vuser ramp down details***, this graph can only collate the details for ***running vusers***. 
Let me know if there is a way to 
(i) collate accurate time for vusers throughout the test in graph data
(ii) collate details of running and exiting vusers in raw data

[Graph Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsLbC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Change the granularity of your graph

Comment: I dispute your comment.  The default granularity of the graph is going to be large enough that the test window graph element is not to the second.   Graph granularity is covered in training, in the tutorial, in the help file, in the manuals and just by right mouse clicking on the graph.   Reduce your granularity in seconds until you get the graph you are seeking.  The answer assumes a familiarity with the mechanics of the tool.

Comment: The comment being disputed has been removed from the poster